# Yielding from within with statement and __exit__ method of context manager

Tags: python, generator, contextmanager

Consider following Python 2.x code snippet.

```
from __future__ import print_function


class myfile(file):
    def __exit__(self, *excinfo):
        print("__exit__ called")
        super(myfile, self).__exit__(*excinfo)


def my_generator(file_name):
    with myfile(file_name) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            yield line.strip()


gen = my_generator('file.txt')
print(next(gen))
print("Before del")
del gen
print("After del")
```

Output of this script (given file.txt has more than one line) is:

```
Line 1 from file
Before del
__exit__ called
After del
```

I'm interested about `__exit__` call specifically.

What triggers execution of his method? For what we know, code never left `with` statement (it "stopped" after `yield` statement and never continued). Is it guaranteed that `__exit__` will be called when reference count of generator drops to 0?

Comment: Second next call was a leftover from not-yet-minimal example. I fixed code snippet, it's accurate now.

Comment: This question is only about CPython?

Comment: It would seem so: semantically it's similar to having a `finally`: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/

Comment: not reference count.  it's not a garbage collection thing.  it happens as soon as you are done with the code block, and all functions called from the code block.  I use it all the time to close database connections - it's kind of a pain to pass the connection object around in function calls, but it works very well at making sure you always close them.  you could try to `fh2 = fh` to see if reference count enters into it, but it shouldn't.

Comment: @JLPeyret: In this case, it actually is a garbage collection thing.

Comment: @MSeifert I'm interested both in CPython implementation and actual language specification.

Comment: @user2357112.  nope.  see my "answer".  remember that the garbage collector is not guaranteed to be called at any point in time.  neither is a `__del__` magic method, though `del` might act diffently.  hardly the behavior you want out of resource closure code.

Comment: @JLPeyret: The way I read the question, it's asking why `__exit__` is called when generator control flow doesn't seem to have flowed out of the `with` block, in which case the answer is "because `__del__` throws a `GeneratorExit` inside the generator".

Comment: so you're saying that the context manager `__exit__` is called on going out of scope or garbage collection, whichever happens earlier.  **which in this particular case is the garbage collection**.  i agree with you on that, so I ditched my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On reclamation of a generator object, Python calls its `close` method, raising a `GeneratorExit` exception at the point of its last `yield` if it wasn't already finished executing. As this `GeneratorExit` propagates, it triggers the `__exit__` method of the context manager you used.

This was introduced in Python 2.5, [in the same PEP as `send` and yield expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/). Before then, you couldn't `yield` inside a `try` with a `finally`, and if `with` statements had existed pre-2.5, you wouldn't have been able to `yield` inside one either.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [@user2357112's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44007670/7051394), the `with` block breaks when an exception is raised inside of it. This exception is passed to the `__exit__` method of the object that was created for the context.

The `file` class seems to pass silently the `GeneratorExit` exception, since nothing signals it. However, if you print `argc` in your `myfile.__exit__` method, you will see that the context was not closed naturally:

```
class myfile(file):
    def __exit__(self, *excinfo):
        print("__exit__ called")
        print(excinfo[0]) # Print the reason why the context exited
        super(myfile, self).__exit__(*excinfo)
```

Output of your script:

```
Line 1 from file
Before del
__exit__ called
<type 'exceptions.GeneratorExit'>
After del
```